# How to programmatically capture email? (like posterous)

Tags: email

I'd like to add a piece of functionality to an app that behaves similar to [Posterous](http://www.posterous.com); in other words, a user would send an email to post@myapp.com. A script would then pick up the email and do something with it. It would also need some sort of authentication, though I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069217/posterous-style-email-verification) answers most of that.

Would I just set up a mail account and then access it via IMAP? Or is there a better way? Would there be a recommended mail server to use for something like this?

The app itself is in Rails, though this script can be in just about anything, I'm comfortable with .NET, python, ruby, or a couple others, though ideally it'd have to easily run on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use fetcher that supports POP3 and IMAP http://github.com/look/fetcher

Comment: That looks pretty interesting. I'll take a look at it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- You can process incoming mail using [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html#Receiving_Mail)
- [Lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/) is a Python email server where you can write 'email apps' like you would write a web app.